# Floating Ground in Renovated Bathroom

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

I am a homeowner and retired RF Engineer, not an electrician.  We bought a house built in 1955 that we have been remodeling in stages over the past five years.  The first thing I had done was to remove the old three phase service and have the utility install new 200A service and have a electrician install new large Square D Homeline panel and new sub-panel for the HVAC. The original wiring is 12 -2 with no ground wire fed from an obsolete GE sub panel with no separate grounding bus. I had new Square D breakers installed in the sub panel. 
We are now close to completion on a kitchen and bath remodel the went down to the studs with entirely new plumbing and electrical.  The kitchen and laundry circuits were removed from the GE panel and are now fed from the new main paned with all new 12-2 Romex.  However, although the bathroom ware rewired, the electrician used the existing feed from the GE panel, thus no ground. The light fixtures and outlets all have ground wires connected together but this ground is just floating. When I bring mu induction tester to the vanity fixture it beeps, even if the wall switch is off.  He installed standard duplex outlet just outside the bathroom connected to this floating ground.
Apparently enough coupling from ground to neutral exists to allow the ground test neon light to illuminate in a tester so the circuit read good.  A home run to the bathroom would have been easy when the walls were open, other new runs were installed within a few feet. Don’t know how they missed this because I told them at the start that I didn’t want shortcuts and wanted a real ground in the bathroom.
 My electrician is saying that this is OK, nothing to be concerned about and that I am just being obsessive. I am asking here because I am not satisfied with what my contractor and electrician are telling me.  I really don’t want to rat him out to the inspector so, if he will not correct this, I’ll try to route a ground wire to the new dryer outlet on the other side of the (concrete block) wall.
Any though from the experts here?

Comment: Coupling from ground to neutral is only allowed in the main panel but I'll leave that to the experts who will chime in shortly.

Comment: Given a choice between safe and code legal work, and hork-a-dorking something together that kinda works but will be written up when you try to sell the house, which are you after?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of that old GE subpanel?

Comment: I want safe and code legal work, final inspection had not yet occurred, they pulled permit for the kitchen, not sure about the bathroom.  I was livid when I found the floating ground.  I'll see if they did any corrective work while I was away.  Not sure how to add photo yet but the GE 20A twin breakers were type TR.

Answer (score 1):

> fed from an obsolete GE sub panel with no separate grounding bus. I had new Square D breakers installed in the sub panel.

### Am I reading this right that you put Square D breakers in a GE subpanel?  Who did this work?

You can't put random brand X  breaker in brand Y panel.  Yes, I know some will "fit" and feel like they snap in, *if you completely ignore what insertion force is normal*. But the buses won't match up, and they will arc.

If you stick with the OEM breakers/panel combo, those are UL listed to work together.  UL will also *classify* certain specific breakers to work in certain specific other panels: Take the 3/4" wide Square D "QO" panel. Eaton CHQ (not CH) or Siemens QD breakers are UL-*classified* because they have passed design review and every safety test.

Are Square D HOM breakers classified for GE panels? ***No they are not, they are definitely not***. I know that because Square D has decried the entire concept of classified breakers, condemns use of ANY other breakers in their panel, and refuses to make classified breakers for anyone else's panel.

So those breakers definitely do not belong in that panel.  Now if you get us photos of the panel and particularly the labeling, we have experts here who can tell you *exactly* what breakers are UL listed (or classified) for that panel.

Yeah, yeah, your guy has been doing this for 20 years and never has any callbacks on any of his alien breaker swaps.  That he knows of.

> the electrician used the existing feed from the GE panel, thus no ground. The light fixtures and outlets all have ground wires connected together but this ground is just floating. When I bring mu induction tester to the vanity fixture it beeps, even if the wall switch is off.

Where is your induction tester getting a ground reference?  can you try it with a solid ground reference taken off a panel cover? Any wire will do to bring ground for testing. Phone line, ethernet, RG58, whatever you can lay your hands on.

> He installed standard duplex outlet just outside the bathroom connected to this floating ground.
>   Apparently enough coupling from ground to neutral exists to allow the ground test neon light to illuminate in a tester so the circuit read good.

Are you sure? That would be **an awful lot** of coupling.  I have never seen capacitive coupling deliver enough EMF to move the needle on a mechanical voltmeter, nevermind light a light.  That's why we see it  reported so much of late: modern DVMs are sensitive enough to detect it.

> A home run to the bathroom would have been easy when the walls were open, other new runs were installed within a few feet. Don’t know how they missed this because I told them at the start that I didn’t want shortcuts and wanted a real ground in the bathroom.

Are you entirely sure he didn't **retrofit ground**? That is perfectly proper and legal as of 2014 NEC.  There is no need for the ground wire to travel the same route as the conductors, since ground wires only carry fault currents.

In fact, a ground retrofit doesn't even need to go back to the panel.  It can reach anywhere that has a ground wire that is thick enough, though it's supposed to be something served out of the same subpanel.  It can also go to any non-flexible metallic conduit, or the grounding electrode system.  (Not water pipes, though).

> I’ll try to route a ground wire to the new dryer outlet on the other side of the (concrete block) wall.

Maybe that's what they **did**.

But do it also, sure.  Worst case you have a redundant parallel ground, and that is allowed because current only travels on grounds during fault conditions. (DON'T use the same logic to parallel anything else).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response!  Regarding the GE panel, yes, I questioned the new breakers but he said they were compatible.  This was done about four years ago, not sure who.  In any case it is better than the old breakers because a contractor deliberately shorted a line to locate the breaker and non tripped.  That when I had the electrician put in new breakers.  I am trying to get rid of the GE panel completely but I'll send a photo in the meantime.

Comment: I know for a fact that the bathroom circuit is not grounded.  I measure 78V with a DVM between hot and ground, should be full line voltage.  The small tester shows two yellow lights indicating good circuit so I initially thought that the installation was OK but a high quality surge protector shows a red fault light.  The inductive tester only beep on the bathroom fixtures, not on any other fixture in the house.

Comment: Incidentally, another electrician did work for a bathroom renovation on the other side of the house and used old wiring to the GE box.. He re-purposed an unused run as a ground but connected it to the neutral in the GE box.  I objected and he said it't OK, it goes to the same place.  Seems that these guys take the NEC as just suggestions.

Comment: The original electrician that put in the new panels and service did an excellent job, however, he passed away and I have yet to find a good one. I no longer trust any here in Myrtle Beach. May have to have a talk with the city inspectors but that may open a whole can of worms.  I am trying to do the right thing and feel that I have had all the really bad stuff fixed (we found lots as we opened walls).

Comment: I still have the original GE breakers, dual 20A GE Type TR (now obsolete i think) circa 1955

Comment: Ask a question about the GE panel once you have photos.  Some panel types aged VERY well and are fully supported today, and there may be no reason to replace it.  Missing ground bar is normal. Most panels today ship with no ground bars, but they are an accessory that is field fitted where needed.

Comment: Just a thought, could it be e sneak path between the ground and neutral in the bathroom GFIC?  Would need to remove the GFI and test again.

Comment: @Robert he is correct that ground and neutral go to the same place.  But... They are the same inside the main panel.  Anywhere else, the **difference** between neutral and ground is **the entire reason we run them separately**. (kind of obvious when you think about it that way).  It became mandatory to separate N and G in subpanels in the 1980s I think. The old GE panel is *grandfathered* meaning what he did was legal.  However, if the GE panel proves to be fully supported, I would separate N and G there.

Comment: @Robert GFCI devices don't interact with ground at all.  They are a black box with Line L and Line N input, and Load L and Load N output.  No connect to ground. (the ground wire on a GFCi receptacle is only there to serve the ground pin on the sockets).   If where you measured is on the protected side, I would expect it to measure 120V not 85V.